# How do I make my numbers input dynamic without having a submit button?

Tags: javascript

https://codepen.io/justinwilldoit/pen/poyZaLv

lets say the bill amount were entered incorrectly and we realized after all the other inputs were in. How can we go back and change the numbers input while also getting the rest of the numbers to change along with it. Here is a link to my JS on codepen. I have also attached some on this post because it is forcing me to.

````
tipForm.onchange = function() {
    people.oninput = function() {
        numberOfPeople.innerHTML = this.value;
    }
    
    percentage.oninput = function() {
        tipPercentage.innerHTML = this.value + '%';
    }
    bill.onchange = function() {
        bill.value = this.value;
    }
    
    tip = (bill.value * (Number(percentage.value/100))).toFixed(2);
    totalTip.innerHTML = '$' + tip;
    total = Number(bill.value) + Number(bill.value) * (Number(percentage.value/100));
    totalAmount.innerHTML = '$' + total;
    split = (total / people.value).toFixed(2);
    splitAmount.innerHTML =  '$' + split;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a variable to be dependent on the values of other variables. I would make it a function instead so the the value is always calculated when it is being used. I would also suggest not defining other functions in an onchange function.